# Why create data binding button not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I read [this article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-Custom-Controls-a031a7ea) and in step 5  :

[image]

I can't click create data binding button :

[image]

(in the properties panel)

It's just inactive. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these five steps to create such a UserControl, then I could reproduce this issue in target version 16299 project.

The workaround is switching the target version to 15063.

[image]

I also suggested that you could report this issue to [Visual Studio Developer community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).